# Bluetooth and MSP430G2

Tags: com, bluetooth, serial-port, connection, msp430

I took MSP430G2 and Bluetooth (JY-MCU Bluetooth Wireless Serial Port Module). Today I decided to try them and tied them in the following manner as explained http://galfama.blogspot.com/2013/02/control-de-leds-del-msp430-launchpad.html . All downloaded super and application Android BlueTerm, let the application run, and MSP-it got the following program:

```
char valor=0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()  //Bucle infinito
{
    if (Serial.available())//Si hay una caracter en el buffer serial
    { 
        valor = Serial.read();// Se lee el valor numérico en el puerto serie.
        Serial.print(valor);  
    }
}
```

Connect to the bluetooth and when I start to write nothing happens. Dropped a Putty, but there nothing, nothing appears. However, when the two exchanged cable (TXD) and (RXD). Putty and run the program and when I write something in Putty appear symbols. If anyone can help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your problem. And here's what he was. My numbers chip is M430G2553, I compiled and uploaded for M430G2452. And hence the problem.

For writing the program code used [Energia](http://energia.nu/download/). Comfortable me because it is one written for Arduino. Will definitely go then C, but for starters I think it's great.

Here is a picture of what chip concerns

[image]